# gtk python - text view scroll to bottom when text is added?

Tags: python, gtk

I am making an application with gtk and python.
In the application I have a scroll window and inside of it I have a textview.
When I use `set_text()` in the textbuffer the scroll bar scrolls to the top.

What I want is when I use `set_text()` is that scroll bar will scroll to the bottom.

Or in other words I want to control the scroll bar to go to the bottom.

How can it be done?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe there are 2 ways.

1. Obtain GtkAdjustments for scrolled window (vertical and horizontal), set it's value to maximum after `set_text`
2. A bit more complicated example can be found in `gtk3-demo` app in `Text Widget -> Automatic Scrolling` section. There are following lines:

`/* If we want to scroll to the end, including horizontal scrolling,
  * then we just create a mark with right gravity at the end of the
  * buffer. It will stay at the end unless explicitly moved with
  * gtk_text_buffer_move_mark.
  */
 gtk_text_buffer_create_mark (buffer, "end", &iter, FALSE);`

And then:

```
/* Get "end" mark. It's located at the end of buffer because
 * of right gravity
 */
mark = gtk_text_buffer_get_mark (buffer, "end");
gtk_text_buffer_get_iter_at_mark (buffer, &iter, mark);

/* and insert some text at its position, the iter will be
 * revalidated after insertion to point to the end of inserted text
 */
// Extra code removed

/* Now scroll the end mark onscreen.
 */
gtk_text_view_scroll_mark_onscreen (textview, mark);
```